# First Practice Project in Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, Ch. 9

Tags: python, shutil

So my friend and I have been having a problem with the first practice project of the above chapter of Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. The prompt goes: "Write a program that walks through a folder tree and searches for files with a certain file extension (such as .pdf or .jpg). Copy these files from whatever location they are in to a new folder."

To simplify, we are trying to write a program that copies all of the .jpg files out of My Pictures to another directory. Here's our code:

```
#! python3
# moveFileType looks in My Puctures and copies .jpg files to my Python folder

import os, shutil

def moveFileType(folder):
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for subfolder in subfolders:
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
                    shutil.copy(folder + filename, '<destination>')

moveFileType('<source>')
```

We keep getting an error along the lines of "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Edit: I added a "\" to the end of my source path (I'm not sure if that is what you meant, @Jacob H), and was able to copy all of the .jpg files in that directory, but received an error when it tried to copy a file within a subfolder of that directory. I added a for loop for subfolder in subfolders and I no longer get any errors, but it doesn't actually look in the subfolders for .jpg files.

Comment: '<destination>' is not a path, this is likely the issue that you are having. You should change <destination> and <source> to the actual destination and source paths. Besides this, check what is contained in the variable 'folder', it might not end with the '/' that you need for a proper file path.

Comment: Also, you can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?os.path.join#os.path.join) to join one or more path components intelligently.

Comment: <destination> and <source> are actual paths in my code, sorry for the confusion! @JacobH

Answer (score 3):

There is a more fundamental problem with your code.  When you use `os.walk()` it will already loop through every directory for you, so looping manually through the subfolders is going to produce the same results multiple times.

The other, and more immediate, problem is that `os.walk()` produces relative file names, so you need to glue them back together.  Basically you are omitting the directory name and looking in the current directory for files which `os.walk()` is finding down in a subdirectory somewhere.

Here's a quick attempt at fixing your code:

```
def moveFileType(folder):
    for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(folderName, filename), '<destination>')
```

Making the function accept a `destination` parameter as a second argument, instead of hardcoding `<destination>`, would make it a lot more useful for the future.

Comment: I added the code you recommended and it was able to find one more .jpg in a subdirectory, but not several other .jpgs in the same subdirectory and another subdirectory.

Comment: Works for me. The code is case-sensitive, though; maybe you want `filename.lower().endswith('.jpg')` to normalize case before comparing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to type the source file destination address correctly. While i tested your code, i wrote

```
moveFileType('/home/anum/Pictures')
```

and i got error;

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

and when i wrote

```
moveFileType('/home/anum/Pictures/')
```

the code worked perfectly... 
Try doing that, hope that will do your work. M using Python 2.7

Herez the re defined code for walking into subfolders and copying ,jpg files from there aswell.

```
import os, shutil

def moveFileType(folder): 
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder): 
               for file in files: 
                   if file.endswith('.jpg'):
                    image_path=os.path.join(root,file)  # get the path location of each jpeg image.
                    print 'location: ',image_path 
                    shutil.copy(image_path, '/home/anum/Documents/Stackoverflow questions')


moveFileType('/home/anum/Pictures/')
```

Comment: I added the slash and it worked! Now I'm having difficulty getting it to search the subfolders. I've updated my post with the new code.